# ApplicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames()

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

How can i replicate  ApplicationDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames() on Adobe Flash Player 9?

```
var definitions:*;
        var g:String="";
        var te:String="";
        var arrayDto:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();
        if (moduloFunzione.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.hasOwnProperty("getQualifiedDefinitionNames")) {
            definitions = moduloFunzione.loaderInfo.applicationDomain["getQualifiedDefinitionNames"]();
          for (var i:int = 0; i < definitions.length; i++) {
            g=definitions[i];
            te=g.substr(g.length-3,g.length-1)
            if (te=="Dto")
            {
                arrayDto.addItem(g);
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the flash.utils.* package

getDefinitionByName / getQualifiedClassName / getQualifiedSuperclassName

are all defined for AIR 1 / FP 9 / FL 4

Comment: If you have the 'static' swf (someone's 3rd party at compile time) - there are tools which show metrics for this sort of thing. I personally use FlashDevelop which will show a breakdown of the swf in: classes, assets, frames, properties, etc.